# Handle null in stream without filtering

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to iterate over a `Map` using the streams API, but, if any `null` occurs in an element of the `EntrySet`, I want to do some custom handling.

Since , I need custom handling of nulls , I cannot just use `Stream::filter`

Using my current function (`MyClass::f`),

```
HashMap<String,String> map =new HashMap<>(); 
map.entrySet().stream().map(MyClass::f);
```

I get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You can pass a functional interface with an if statement or a ternary conditional operator to whatever Stream operation (`map`,`forEach`,...) you wish to put your logic in.

Comment: HashMap<String,String> map =new HashMap<>();
        map
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(//lambda);

This code would throw NPE , I want to handle null and avoid NPE

Comment: that has to do with `lambda` then. `map.entrySet().stream().map(x -> {return x;});` will work fine for example.

Comment: @shmosel I was thinking ConcurrentHashMap. NM - comment deleted.

Comment: @midor , you were right it was the lamdba

Comment: @ManasSaxena: I think you questions was legitimate, but if you want to keep this around, I think you should put in some effort to rephrase it, i.e. filling in what function you used, to actually make it useful for others, who may make the same mistake.

Answer (score 3):

`map` with a function that handles the `null`, and returns the original for other objects.

Without a concrete use-case this is the best I can provide:

```
List<String> s = Arrays.asList("foo", null, "bar", null);
s.stream()
  .map(e -> (e == null) ? "woops, something was null" : e)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

should give you

```
foo 
woops, something was null
bar
woops, something was null
```

Comment: can you please provide some code here , am very new to  java8

Comment: sure, if you provide an example of what you would want to map over.

Comment: map.entrySet().stream().map() this code gives me NPE, so basically just want that whenever  map.entrySet().stream() is null then print error , if not null then call map.entrySet().stream().map(lamdba)

Comment: are you sure `map` is not `null`?

Comment: Yes I am sure about that

Comment: If it is really the stream that is `null` you will have to add some sample code, because AFAIK, `entrySet()` would return empty on empty, and otherwise always a valid set, which would return the empty stream on empty and otherwise an empty stream. Unless you use some custom implementation that violates the contract that is, of course. If it is the elements, you can apply the technique shown above.

Comment: For example:

HashMap<String,String> map =new HashMap<>(); map.entrySet() .stream() .map(//lambda);

This code gives me NPE

Comment: Your code would do exactly the same without the `.map(e -> (e == null) ? "null" : e)` step. @ManasSaxena: if `HashMap<String,String> map =new HashMap<>(); map.entrySet() .stream() .map(lambda);` throws an NPE, `lambda` must be `null`. After all, there are no `null`s in an empty map and the stream without a terminal operation didn’t even process any elements if there were some.

Comment: updated, to make it clear that the map step represents special treatment of a null-value